# using pandas to_csv to write the result to a csv in different sheets

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

The following code creates a csv named `assetinventory.csv` using data from the DataFrame:

```
data.append([x, instancename, names])
pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['InstanceID','InstanceName','AppCode']).to_csv('assetinventory.csv', mode='a',header=False,index=False)
```

Now I want to create a Sheet2 when I write to the same CSV file again. How can I do that?

Comment: CSV files don't have worksheets - you are probably thinking of an Excel spreadsheet and the Pandas function `to_excel()`. Please edit your question to clarify what you're after.

Comment: Hey Your response has given me answer. Thank you.